# MPI - sending and receiving rows of matrix

Tags: c, mpi

I am making program, where will be 2-4 processes in MPI with C language. In elimination I am sending each row below actual row to different processes by cyclic mapping.

e.g. for matrix 5 * 6, when there is active row 0, and 4 processes, I am sending row 1 to process 1, row 2 to the process 2, row 3 to the process 3 and row 4 to the process 1 again. In theese processes I want to make some computation and return some values back to the process 0, which will add theese into its original matrix. My question is, which Send and Recv call should I use?

There is some theoretical code:

```
if(master){

  for(...)
  //sending values to other processes
  }

  for(...)
  //recieving values from other processes
  }
}else{//for other non-master processes
  recieve value from master
  doing some computing
  sending value back to master

}
```

If I use only simple blocking send, I don't know what will happen on process 1, because it gets row 1 and 4, and before I will cal recv in master, my value in process 1 - row 1 will be overwritten by row 4, so I will miss one set of data, am I right? My question on therfore, what kind of MPI_Send should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to make use of nonblocking if, say, proc 1 can start doing something with row 1 while waiting for row 4.  But blocking should be fine to start with, too.

There is a lot of synchronization built into the algorithm.   Everyone has to work based on the current row.   So the recieving processes will need to know how much work to expect for each iteration of this procedure.   That's easy to do if they know the total number of rows, and which iteration they're currently working on.   So if they're expecting two rows, they could do two blocking recvs, or launch 2 nonblocking recvs, wait on one, and start processing the first row right away.   But probably easiest to get blocking working first.

You may find it advantageous even at the start to have the master process doing isends so that all the sends can be "launched" simulataneously; then a waitall can process them in whatever order.

But better than this one-to-many communication would probably be to use a scatterv, which one could expect to proceed more efficiently.

Something that has been raised in many answers and comments to this series of questions but which I don't think you've ever actually addressed -- I really hope that you're just working through this project for educational purposes.   It would be completely, totally, crazy to actually be implementing your own parallel linear algebra solvers when there are tuned and tested tools like [Scalapack](http://www.netlib.org/scalapack/), [PETSc](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-as/), and [Plapack](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/plapack/) out there free for the download.